# Системное сообщение, вместо красивого экрана загрузки Ubutnu

Tags: ubuntu

Во время загрузки системы, вместо экрана загрузки появляется надпись clean blocks **/** (**-числа), как убрать это сообщение и поставить нормальный загрузочный экран?
P.S. файловая система ext4

UPD: dmesg http://my-files.ru/us9ybn

Comment: это нормальный процес

Comment: @Geyan, я понимаю, но это некрасиво выглядит, можно это как-нибудь убрать?

Comment: подобное сообщение не должно появлятся часто. Скорее всего Вы либо неправильно выключаете компьютер, либо диск потихоньку умирает.

Comment: @Fexolm убьёте систему , пускай останется как есть

Comment: @KoVadim, не подскажите, как правильно его выключать?
пробовал простое выключение через gui, sudo reboot, sudo shutdown -h now 
P.S диск - ssd, он точно в норме, проверял - 0 ошибок

Comment: выключение через гуй - вполне нормально для декстопа. Тогда нужно смотреть в dmesg и гадать, почему оно решило запустить проверку.

Comment: @KoVadim это и у меня появляется и всегда , я выключаю через Gui и по другому не умею , ваш совет  не совет , даже на ubuntu.com другого не скажут

Comment: Все-таки, нельзя ли как-нибудь скрыть эти сообщения, мой внутренний перфекционист бушует..

Comment: понятно, смотреть в dmesg не хотите, а пусть лучше телепаты угадают, что у Вас там происходит. Я навскидку знаю ещё как минимум два варианта. Например, кто то пошутил и дал команду `tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdXX` (sdXX - Ваш диск, скорее всего sda1) и он будет проверятся при каждой загрузке. Либо, какая то утилита создает файлик `/forcefsck`  каждый раз.

Скрыть... если у человека чесотка, то ее нужно лечить, а не прикрывать пудрой.

Comment: @KoVadim, я с радостью посмотрю dmesg, но я не знаю, что там искать. Если сообщения об ошибках выводятся красным цветом, то там только одна ошибка [    3.865132] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device

Comment: надо найти там начало проверки диска и посмотреть на пару строк выше, что ее запустило.

Comment: @KoVadim, выложил dmesg на файлообменник, приложил ссылку к посту, боюсь самому разобраться в логах у меня не получится

Comment: здесь http://askubuntu.com/questions/761653/startup-problem-in-16-04-lts все  написано.

Comment: @KoVadim, Почитал вашу ссылку, как я понял, это всего лишь проверка диска на наличие ошибок перед запуском. Но решения моей проблемы по ссылке не нашел. Как я понял, смысла отключать эту проверку нет, а значит мне нужно скрыть следы ее работы. Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46510/discussion-between-fexolm-and-kovadim).